# beam dataflow python name 'PipelineOptions' is not defined

Tags: python, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I want to create very simple pipeline and already get stuck at the beginning. Here comes my code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = 'myproject'
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'mypipe'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://mybucket/staging'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://mybucket/temp'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
```

Produces the Error:

```
NameError: name 'PipelineOptions' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The module code has changed from **apache_beam.utils** to **apache_beam.option** :

You should now use:

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
```

Official documentation here : https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.0.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some additional imports for the example to work:

```
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.utils.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from apache_beam.pipeline import PipelineOptions
options = PipelineOptions()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.